How to set origin point to base of object?
I am trying to set a geometry node setup to animate letters in a word.
As I was struggling to separate letters in Geo nodes I wrote a script to convert text into mesh and then separate by loose parts.
However I am stuck with setting the origin at the right place so the letters will rotate correctly and will end up in the right position in the word by the end of the animation.
First, if you have an idea how to separate words into letters in Geo that will be a great help.
Second, if not, how to set origin to base of object either with a script or in geo

May I recommend to read this: Geometry nodes instance rotation and scale  and that: how to get the center point of a letter? ?

Here's an example of how you can manage letters as individual instances.

Press "Ctrl+." to change the position of the origin. Don't forget to press "Ctrl+." again to turn it off. Be careful if you forget to realise instances (another node) in geometry nodes, these hotkeys can produce unexpected results.
 (Blender v 4.1.0)

This is great. Thanks. I might be able to reverse the order of the letters since as far as I know, Blender still can't write words that write from right to left correctly
